# How do i return the formatted JSON object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httpserver

I am making the following nodejs server

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 1337;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var statusList = {
      "hasErrors": false,
      "list" : [
        { "id": "spec1",
          "name": "retrieve blog info"
        },
        { "id": "spec2",
          "name": "Retrieve a Blog Avatar"
        },
        { "id": "spec3",
          "name": "Retrieve Blog's Likes"
        },
        { "id": "spec4",
          "name": "Retrieve a Blog's Followers"
        }
      ],
      "totalRecords": 4
    };
    console.log(req);
    console.log(statusList);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" });
    res.write(JSON.stringify(statusList));
    res.end();
}).listen(port);
```

But this simply display `statusList` without any format (simply as a string without any space or enter) on the browser page. I want to see the structured formatted `json` in browser so that it is clearly visible.

I also don't want to install any kind of plugin on my browser.

Also note that if i remove `JSON.stringify()` and simply return the object `statusList` as `res.write(statusList);` then i get the error : `'first argument must be a string or buffer'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify(statusList, 0, 4);
```

Instead.